# Android> Google Cloud Messaging vs simple polling for server changes

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Creating an application that needs to be updated when a user registers on a web app. The simplest solution to me seemed to be to integrate a simple client side polling mechanism. But I've read recently about Google Cloud Messaging which would eliminate the need for polling, instead 'pushing' update events to registered devices.

This seems like an unnecessary addition of another layer of complexity, since the GCM server would act as a mediator to the real server.

Can anyone who has used GCM comment? Is it useful in this simple use case where the application is only updated once, or very infrequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I should do something similar, I would integrate the MQTT protocol in my server and in the mobile app. It is explicitly designed for machine to machine. You can find references in the [Mosquitto project web page](http://www.mosquitto.org)

Answer (score 0):

GCM would work fine for you, instead of polling the server where there may or may not be any new data wasting battery in the process where GCM you would only send a push when there is new data to get so the battery is not wasted on unnecessary calls to the server.

that being said google does not guarantee that any device gets the push so you need to take that into account

Comment: In my case, battery power is not a concern. Is polling simply the wrong approach?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with polling but a push when there is new data to get would be the more appropriate solution